# Self-intersecting after exporting .shp from Personal GeoDatabase

Tags: arcgis-desktop, personal-geodatabase, feature-dataset, self-intersection

I have a Feature Dataset in a Personal Geodatabase, with resolution = 0.00000001 and tolerance = 0.000000005.

I am exporting the Polygon Feature Classes to shapefiles, after setting Resolution = 0.0001 in the Environment Settings of the Export tool (generalising them).

The resulting shapefiles have too many self-intersecting polygons (reported by the Check Geometry Tool), while the FCs in the GeoDB were Ok!

Any suggestions?

I know these settings in the GeoDB look ridiculous, but it's not my choice...

Comment: You should probably use a proper Generalize tool instead of just truncating coordinates and hoping for the best.

Comment: Your data is probably in Geographic coordinate system. .0001 is much too large for Geographic (decimal degrees) but is good for Projected SR such as meters, feet units.

Comment: My data is in GGR87 (Projection, not Geographic). My raw data are in AutoCAD, from there I exported polygon shapefiles (from AutoCAD topologies). Those .shp were first validated (check geometry gives no errors) and then imported into the GeoDB. The exported shapefiles (from the GeoDB) have many problems. ????

Answer (score 1):

It seems the problem was in **AutoCAD**.

The .dwg was opened and saved in v.2010 and then re-opened in v.2014.

When I fetched the objects by a query (in ACAD Map - attach dwg - query), it seemed there were some 'invisible' objects.

When i did the same procedure in ACAD (topology - export shp - import in Feature Dataset of a GeoDB - export shp), the problem was gone!